# Old picture is missing

Tags: php

So I have "staff" table in database i.e. StaffName, StaffAddress and StaffProfilePicture etc. Updating works fine on name, address but not the picure. The old picture seems to be missing from the database eventhough I don't upload a new one.

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $target_dir = "images/staff/";
        $target_dir = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["new_profilepicture"]["name"]);
        $uploadOk=1;

        if (file_exists($target_dir . $_FILES["new_profilepicture"]["name"])) {
        //echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
        if ($uploadOk==0) {
        //echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    } 
    else { 
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["new_profilepicture"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir)) {
        $imageup = $target_dir;
        //echo "<img src='" . $imageup . "' />";
    } else {
        //echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
        $_var1 = $_POST['new_name'];
        $_var2 = $_POST['new_email'];
        $_var3 = $_POST['new_password'];
        $_var4 = $_POST['new_contactno'];
        $_var5 = $_POST['new_icno'];
        $_var6 = $_POST['new_address'];
        $_var7 = $_POST['new_status'];
        $_var8 = $imageup;

        $query1 =   $mysqli->query("UPDATE staff
                            SET StaffName='$_var1', StaffEmail='$_var2', StaffPassword='$_var3', StaffContactNo='$_var4', StaffICNo='$_var5', StaffAddress='$_var6', StaffStatus='$_var7', StaffProfilePicture='$_var8'
                            WHERE StaffID='$staffID'");

        $success = mysql_query($query1);//is mysql query working?

            if($success){
                //$oldprofilepicture = $staff['StaffProfilePicture'];
                //if(file_exists($oldprofilepicture)){
                    //unlink($oldprofilepicture);//delete now
            echo "success";
            header('location:staff_profile.php');
            die;
            }else{
            echo "failed";
            }
        }
```

Below is the HTML form for the picture

```
<tr>
    <td width="170">Old Profile Picture:</td>
    <td><img src="<?php echo $profilepicture ?>" width="100" height="80" /><br><br>
        <input type="file" name="new_profilepicture" />
</tr>
```

**How can I make the old/existed picture stay?**

Comment: You are using both `mysqli` and `mysql` extensions, the latter being deprecated. You can't do `mysql_query($query1)` with `$query1` being a `mysqli` query object. That's probably why it is not working. By the way; your code is susceptible to injection

Comment: Please edit your post so the text looks like it does in your editor.  It's hard to read the way it is now.

Comment: If this code is live, I recommend you take it down. Not only it is likely to get hacked, but you appear to be storing user passwords in plaintext too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your query you have:

StaffProfilePicture='$_var8'

so it still updates the database and since $imageup is empty/undefined so is $_var8 and it will update the database with empty value.

So add an if condition:

```
$_var8 = $imageup;

if($_var8 != '') {
    $query1 =   $mysqli->query("UPDATE staff SET StaffName='$_var1', StaffEmail='$_var2', StaffPassword='$_var3', StaffContactNo='$_var4', StaffICNo='$_var5', StaffAddress='$_var6', StaffStatus='$_var7', StaffProfilePicture='$_var8' WHERE StaffID='$staffID'");
} else {
    $query1 =   $mysqli->query("UPDATE staff SET StaffName='$_var1', StaffEmail='$_var2', StaffPassword='$_var3', StaffContactNo='$_var4', StaffICNo='$_var5', StaffAddress='$_var6', StaffStatus='$_var7' WHERE StaffID='$staffID'");
}
```

or you can do it other ways but that's where your problem is that you're losing your old image. Hope it helps.

Cheers.

Comment: Oh yes. Thank you! And um, one more favour, the header doesn't work. It doesn't go to staff_profile.php after clicking save button. Can you help me please?

Comment: Drop: $success = mysql_query($query1); and just use if($query1) as it will return true if successful or otherwise false